# Sencha Touch 2: Load too many views and controllers in app.js

Tags: javascript, cordova, sencha-touch

I have an app that initially load lots of views and controllers in app.js and when I package it with Phonegap the app starts too slow.

Is there any way to load them dynamically without loading them in the app.js and without receiving the warning "Synchronously loading ... consider adding ... explicitly as a require'

Here's the code:

```
views: [             
    'UserProfile',
    'Record',
    'AllOptions',
    'Login',
    'ForgotPassword',
    'Pin',
    'Newsletter',
    'UserHome',
    'Settings',
    'About',
    'UserCard',
    'RecordDetail',
    'AboutDetail',
    'NewPIN',
    'SubjectDetail'
],

controllers: ['MainController', 'LoginController', 'NewsletterController', 'SettingsController', 'AllOptionsController', 'ProfileController', 'UserCardController','RecordController','AboutController', 'SubscriptionsController'],

models: ['New', 'Message', 'SettingsAction','StudentRecord','Faculty','SubjectRecord'],
stores: ['NewsStore', 'MessagesStore', 'SettingsActionsStore','StudentRecordStore', 'FacultysStore', 'StudentSubjectStore'],
```

Comment: can you provide your code ? classes , methods...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controllers needs to be configured in the controllers section of the App. In fact during launch, each `Controller.init()` function is called **before** the `App.launch()`

From http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.app.Application:

> Each Application can define a launch function, which is called as soon as all of your 
>   app's classes have been loaded and the app is ready to be launched.
>   This is usually the best place to put any application startup logic,
>   typically creating the main view structure for your app.
>
> In addition to the Application launch function, there are two other
>   places you can put app startup logic. Firstly, each Controller is able
>   to define an init function, which is called before the Application launch function. 
>   Secondly, if you are using Device Profiles, each Profile can define a
>   launch function, which is called after the Controller init functions
>   but before the Application launch function.
>
> Note that only the active Profile has its launch function called - for
>   example if you define profiles for Phone and Tablet and then launch
>   the app on a tablet, only the Tablet Profile's launch function is
>   called.
>
> Controller#init functions called Profile#launch function called
>   Application#launch function called Controller#launch functions called
>   When using Profiles it is common to place most of the bootup logic
>   inside the Profile launch function because each Profile has a
>   different set of views that need to be constructed at startup.

But you can avoid defining all the views in the App views section if any of them is actually a subview of another (is going to be used only if the parent view will be used):

Views have a `requires` configuration which you can use to require the subviews or components they need, while, Controllers have the `views` configuration:

So, let's say you have this dependency tree:

```
home
|-> contacts
   |-> contact form
   |-> contact list
   |-> contact detail
|-> news
```

Instead of requiring form, list and detail views into the app.js you can require those in the contacts controller.

This has the advantage that if at a second time you will cease using the contacts section, you will remove contacts controller from the app and the subviews will be no more included in your app code.

Every time you see the `"Synchronously loading ... consider adding ... explicitly as a require"` in the console logs, it means that you need to add that component (both if it is a custom view you made or a Sencha framework component) to the `requires` section in the proper view. This way when you build a package for production deploy using Sencha command, the compile script can add only the component that will be actually used and it will produce a smaller package.